# grunt configure settings file dynamically

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have two files that get loaded, shown below.  I want to dynamically load the settings file by name in properties.js.  I want to replace <%= settings["build.target.environment"] %> with the value from the environment build option.  Whenever i try to replace the value i get a compilation error in grunt.  Basically, cant load tasks, X task isnt found because no tasks loaded properly.  I have an alias called init that runs both of these items in order. How can i get the build option into the properties file so i can dynamically load the config i want to load.  or is there another option?  It seems like my build option wouldnt be picked up at the time these files load.

please bear with me and any ignorances with grunt, relatively new to grunt.

properties.js:

```
module.exports = {
  settings: 'config/build.properties',
  instance: 'config/environment.<%= settings["build.target.environment"] %>.properties'
}
```

buildoptions.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.registerTask('buildoptions', 'set build version and repo branch', function() {
    var build = grunt.option("build");
    var branch = grunt.option("branch") || '';
    var environment = grunt.option("environment");

    grunt.config('build', build);
    grunt.config('branch', branch);
    grunt.config('environment', environment)
  });

};
```

aliases.json:

```
"init": [  
    "buildoptions",
    "properties"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set local variables to access `grunt.option` values within template strings, instead reference it directly:

```
module.exports = {
  settings: 'config/build.properties',
  instance: "config/environment.<%= grunt.option('environment') %>.properties"
}
```

Comment: do i not need the environment info in the build options file at all?

Comment: this throws an error: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/DEV22/grunt/config/properties.js:3
  instance: 'config/environment.<%= grunt.option('environment') %>.properties'
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...[31mERROR[39m

Comment: looks like i just needed to escape the single quotes with \'environment\'

Comment: Oversight on my part, had a nested pair of single quotes.  No need for escaping, just copy the updated string that's wrapped with double quotes

Comment: thanks for the info, works with the escaping too just fyi